# Does React update all the variables and objects dependent on Component State if the state get updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I wanted to ask that if a component State is changed, does React only re-renders the component or it updates all the objects dependent on state as well.

Comment: This question is too broad without an example, "dependent on state" how? Depended as used in props? Yes. Depended on a portion of a state? Depends. Provide some code example, also you can just check it by logging in a render function. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Children components are involved in the (cascade) rendering if any of their props change as effect of the containing component.

Comment: Not a full answer, by default, children are rendered if their parent has been renderd, even if their props didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

A change in component state will trigger a rerender of all child components.
You can change this behaviour by using a PureComponent (which only rerenders when it detects changes to props):

```
const Child = () => {
  console.log("child rendering");
  return <p>child</p>;
};

class PureChild extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("pure child rendering");
    return <p>PureChild</p>;
  }
}
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {"state: " + state}
      <Child />
      <Child />
      <Child />
      <PureChild />
      <PureChild />
      <PureChild />
      <button onClick={() => setState(!state)}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-swirles-vt30d?file=/src/App.js